# О работе phpinfo()

Tags: php, php.ini

Почему `phpinfo()` и `php.ini` показывают разные результаты?

Файлов `.htaccess` я нигде не использовал. Правда, на компе стоит 4 сервера Apache. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим? `Short_open_tag` проверял, работает.

[image]

Comment: Ну и за что минус, @karmadro4?

Comment: За 4 сервера апач возможно...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотри в phpinfo какой ini файл php смотрит:

Как-то так, в самом начале:

```
Loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

Вообще может быть не поменялось значение из-за того что ты Apache не перезагрузил.

Comment: Срасибо, сработало. Оказывается забыл в Apache установить директиву.